# Why is keyframes working on Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added some waypoints so that the animation is activated when scrolling down. The animation that changes the opacity from 0 to 1 works perfectly, but the rotation animation only works on Firefox. Why is it?

```
    .icon-animate{
        opacity: 1;
        animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes icon-rotation{
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes icon-rotation{
        0% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        100% {
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try also adding prefix to `animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;`

Comment: ↑↑↑ `-webkit-animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also add prefix to `animation`, see the follows.

```
.icon-animate{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
    -moz-animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
    animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
}
```

```css
.icon-animate{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
    -moz-animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
    animation: icon-rotation 750ms linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes icon-rotation{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes icon-rotation{
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-animate">demo</div>
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mpu08kwx/